# Does "Hucksters & Hexes" Remove the Hexslingin' Aptitude?

Tags: deadlands-classic

Assuming you use the rules in "Hucksters & Hexes", is Hexslingin' no longer an aptitude? "Hucksters & Hexes" makes it sound like each hex is an aptitude. Is this interpretation accurate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No. In fact, it's the opposite.**

In the original *Deadlands* rulebook, each spell was its own Aptitude, to be bought up individually. That rule was changed to the Hexslingin' attribute for *Hexarcana* and the *Deadlands Player's Guide*. So you're right to keep using Hexslingin', as that's the newer rule.